# How would you convert secs to HH:MM:SS format in SQLite?

Tags: datetime, sqlite, string-formatting

How would you convert secs to HH:MM:SS format in SQLite?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this one:

```
sqlite> SELECT time(10, 'unixepoch');
00:00:10
```

Comment: This is what I thought originally but used strftime instead of time

Comment: What about the reverse? That is, from 00:00:10 to 10.

Comment: This is limited to time 24 hours or less. Beyond 24 hours, the resulting value is the time of day from the following day(s). i.e. select time(60*60*24+600,'unixepoch') does not yield 24:10; it yields 00:10 (the next day's 10 minutes). The correct answer is by mivk. Formatted time would be printf('%3d', Seconds / 3600)) || ':' || strftime('%M:%S', Seconds / 86400.0)

Answer (score 12):

If your seconds are more than 24 hours, you need to calculate it yourself. For example, with 100123 seconds, rounding down to minutes:

```
SELECT (100123/3600) || ' hours, ' || (100123%3600/60) ||' minutes.'
27 hours, 48 minutes
```

The `time` or `strftime` functions will obviously convert every 24-hours to another day. So the following shows 3 hours (the time on the next day):

```
SELECT time(100123, 'unixepoch')
03:48:43
```

To get the full 27 hours, you can calculate the hours separately, and then use `strftime` for the minutes and seconds:

```
SELECT (100123/3600) || ':' || strftime('%M:%S', 100123/86400.0);
27:48:43
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i would do something like this, but i'm getting hours plus 12...

```
SELECT strftime('%H-%M-%S', CAST(<seconds here> / 86400.0 AS DATETIME)) 

-- For subtracting the 12 hours difference :S
SELECT strftime('%H-%M-%S', CAST(<seconds here> / 86400.0 AS DATETIME) - 0.5)
```

Comment: I think it is adjustjing for the start of the epoch. I know it can work, I will work it out.

Comment: well, thanks for the nudge !!  I thought nobody was going to answer so I dropped it out